# how to run shell script to display command line arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    echo $var
done
```

simple shell script which displays each of the command
line arguments, one at a time and stops displaying command line
arguments when it gets an argument whose value is “stop”.?

Comment: `echo $var` is problematic.  What do you expect your script to do when one of the arguments is `-e` ?   Merely adding quotes around `$var` will not completely solve the problem, but is a good start.

Comment: `printf '%q ' "$@"; echo`

Comment: That said, what's the specific technical problem you encountered that prevents you from doing this yourself?

Comment: for stopping the command line arguments where do i  put the "stop" argument to stop the command line arguments from displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do 
    if [[ "$var" == 'stop' ]]; then
        exit 0
    else
        echo "$var"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `echo $var` is buggy. See [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: THX, have update it.

Answer (score 0):

Process args with a while loop:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while test -n "$1"; do
    test "$1" != 'stop' && echo "$1" && shift || break
done
```

Comment: `foo && bar || baz` is not identical to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`. Better to do the latter and avoid corner cases.

Comment: A chain of "and" conditions can be followed by an "else" in my experience.  Just short hand. I suppose `if then else` is more readable. Can you show me a corner case where my solution fails?

Comment: Sure. In `foo && bar || baz` it's possible for `baz` to run even if `foo` succeeded, should `bar` have a nonzero exit status. (In this case that would mean the write to stdout failing).

Comment: If you run your code through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), the warning it throws is [SC2015](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2015).

Comment: Thank you, Charles. I'll run some tests.

Comment: `true && true || echo 'false'` `A` is a simple true or false, so I'm not worried about that corner case.

Comment: Sure, but the point I made is that `echo "$1"` is not _always_ true. It's _very usually_ true, but relying on that means that in the presence of bugs ("environmental surprises"?) impacting ability to write to stdout, you get _additional_ bugs whereby unexpected codepaths get executed.